# Ayuda con JSON para convertirlo en Array

Tags: swift, xcode

Quisiera saber como podría recibir un Diccionario y Convertirlo en un Arreglo de tipo Clases. El diccionario lo recibo en Json y lo descargo con alamofire. En lo que necesitaría ayuda es en crear la función que me convierta a un vector.

```
import UIKit

enum DiasClases {
    case Lunes
    case Martes
    case Miercoles
    case Jueves
    case Viernes
    case Sabado

    static func allValues() -> [DiasClases] {
        return [Lunes, Martes, Miercoles, Jueves, Viernes, Sabado]
    }
}

struct Clases {
    let id: Int
    let dia: DiasClases
    let horario: String
    let materia: String
    let profesor: String
    let seccion: String
}

func fromDictionary( dictionary: NSDictionary) -> [DiasClases] 
{
    var Clases = [DiasClases]()
    let list = dictionary["Horario"] as? NSArray

    for (IndexSet, value) in Clases.enumerated() {
        Clases.append(Clases)
    }
}
```

Comment: La respuesta de Alamofire ya la tienes parseada a un diccionario? Si pudieras poner un ejemplo del json ayudaría...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que tu JSON sea similar a este:

```
{
  "Horario": [{
      "id": 1234,
      "dia": 1,
      "horario": "16:30-18:30",
      "materia": "Matemáticas",
      "profesor": "Fulanito",
      "sección": "1A"
  }, {
      "id": 1235,
      "dia": 2,
      "horario": "16:30-18:30",
      "materia": "Filosofía",
      "profesor": "Pepito",
      "sección": "1B"
  }]
}

enum DiasClases: Int {
  case Lunes = 1
  case Martes = 2
  case Miercoles = 3
  case Jueves = 4
  case Viernes = 5
  case Sabado = 6

  static func allValues() -> [DiasClases] {
      return [Lunes, Martes, Miercoles, Jueves, Viernes, Sabado]
  }
}


func fromDictionary(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) -> [Clases]
{
    var clases = [Clases]()
    let list = dictionary["Horario"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]

    list?.forEach({ (listItem) in
        let dia = listItem["dia"] as? Int ?? 0
        let clase = Clases(id: listItem["id"] as? Int ?? 0,
                           dia: DiasClases(rawValue: dia),
                           horario: listItem["horario"] as? String ?? "",
                           materia: listItem["materia"] as? String ?? "",
                           profesor: listItem["profesor"] as? String ?? "",
                           seccion: listItem["seccion"] as? String ?? "")
        clases.append(clase)
    })
    return clases
}
```

Comment: Se podria hacer que el enum DiasClases sea de tipo string ya que uso esos datos para cargar en mi vista en un texfield? Y agradezco tu ayuda

Comment: Sí, claro... es q no sé qué información viene en tu Json, así que no sé cuál sería la manera más adecuada... este era solo un ejemplo! Podrías también incluir una variable calculada `displayValue` y con un `switch self` decidir el valor que quieres mostrar en pantalla, por ejemplo... si te ha ayudado recuerda votar la respuesta! ;)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xsquxokz44p7i59/Clases.json?dl=1  este seria el link de mi json lo que estoy queriendo hacer es crear un modelo el cual le paso un json y el me convierte a aun vector, eso ya lo pude hacer gracias a tu código de ejemplo. Lo que no se como hacer es cargar un nuevo vector solo con los días lunes por ejemplo para poder cargar en mi vista de lunes.

Comment: Eso sería tema para otra pregunta, pero básicamente en tu vista de lunes podrías usar el array `clases` y hacerle un `filter`. Algo como: `clases.filter { $0.dia == .Lunes }` y eso te devuelve otro array ya filtrado. Estoy con el móvil y no he podido probarlo, pero debería ser algo similar

Comment: Ok, voy a probar eso te agradezco la ayuda y voy a comentar los resultados

Comment: Hola ahora tengo tiempo de vuelta y retome mi proyecto, y tengo el siguiente problema al querer utilizar la función que me habrías escrito mas arriba fromDictionary me dice que mi vector no es de tipo que adapte al modelo

Comment: Quizá deberías publicar otra pregunta para esto... en cualquier caso, al menos pon como estás usando la función. Cuál es el código que te falla?

Comment: Una consulta, en mi enumerador yo lo puse de tipo string y no uso los números enteros entonces hago un casting a string pero no que no me queda claro es si sigo utilizando el rawvalue porque hasta ahora mi vector no queda cargado con los días correspondiente se queda así (DiasClases?)